# Неожиданный результат функции sizeof()

Tags: c++, структуры, sizeof

```
#include <iostream>
struct Product
{
char product_name[30] = " ";
int price = -1;
}

int main()
{
    Product test;
    std::cout << sizeof(test.product_name) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(test.price) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(test) << std::endl;
}
```

На вывод я получаю:
30
4
36
Откуда взялись ещё два байта?
P.S Сталкиваюсь с таким впервые, в других моих программах такого не происходило.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: data structure alignment

Comment: А что это такое?

Comment: Вы провоцируете меня на комментарий про блокировку в Гугле?

Comment: Почитал, понял, спасибо)

Comment: [Выравнивание данных](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+c%2B%2B).